# Give a combinatorial argument to show that C(n,k) = C(n,n-k)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

What is combinatorial argument and how can i prove this equation ? As far i understand i think we have to apply the Chu-Vandermonde identity but i am not sure if thats right or not.

```
Give a combinatorial argument to show that C(n,k) = C(n,n-k)  ?
```

Comment: There is a group of $n$ kids. There are just as many ways to pick $k$ of them and tell them "you are the winners" as there are to pick $n-k$ of them and say "sorry, you are the losers."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C(n,k)$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ people out of $n$.

$C(n,n-k)$ is the number of ways of choosing $n-k$ people out of $n$.

Suppose we want to divide $n$ people into two groups, one of size $k$ and one of size $n-k$.  Then we could either choose who to put in the first group, or choose who to put in the second group.  Both of these would be equivalent.  Hence, $C(n,k) = C(n,n-k)$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bijection between the ways of choosing $k$ objects and discarding $n-k$ objects from a collection of $n$ objects. Which gives the required identity.

Answer (score 0):

$C(n,k)$ gives the number of the possibilities to choose $k$ Elements from a set of cardinality $n$. This is actually equivalent to partition this set into 2 sets. Each of these sets is uniquely determined by the elements of the other - by choosing $k$ elements we implicitly choose $n-k$ elements and vice versa, so the number of possible choices must be the same in both cases.